# Combine data from consecutive rows

Tags: crystal-reports, informix

I have a query like this

```
SELECT b.studentname,
CASE
    WHEN a.eventtype = 1
    THEN a.eventdatetime
    ELSE NULL
END AS login,
CASE
    WHEN a.eventtype = 7
    THEN a.eventdatetime
    ELSE NULL
END AS logout

FROM student b INNER JOIN logstudent a ON b.studentid = a.studentid
WHERE b.active AND (a.eventtype = 1 OR a.eventtype = 7)
```

the output like this

```
Student name    login                   logout

Toto Imawan     2013-05-08 10:56:46.88  
Toto Imawan                             2013-05-08 11:12:08.279
Toto Imawan     2013-09-23 07:07:54.537 
Toto Imawan                             2013-09-23 07:10:50.362
Toto Imawan     2013-09-23 07:21:18.725 
Toto Imawan                             2013-09-23 07:24:16.831
Toto Imawan     2013-09-23 07:26:06.254 
Toto Imawan                             2013-09-23 07:28:35.427
Toto Imawan     2013-09-23 07:46:49.229 
Toto Imawan                             2013-09-23 07:52:18.691
CCAASTRA.L                              2013-05-07 10:22:14.913
CCAASTRA.L      2013-05-07 12:35:48.136 
CCAASTRA.L                              2013-05-07 13:45:10.366
CCAASTRA.L      2013-05-08 02:23:23.505 
CCAASTRA.L                              2013-05-08 04:18:05.096
```

but that is false output I want the output like this

```
Student name    login                   logout

Toto Imawan     2013-05-08 10:56:46.88  2013-05-08 11:12:08.279
Toto Imawan     2013-09-23 07:07:54.537 2013-09-23 07:10:50.362
Toto Imawan     2013-09-23 07:21:18.725 2013-09-23 07:24:16.831
Toto Imawan     2013-09-23 07:26:06.254 2013-09-23 07:28:35.427
Toto Imawan     2013-09-23 07:46:49.229 2013-09-23 07:52:18.691
CCAASTRA.L                              2013-05-07 10:22:14.913
CCAASTRA.L      2013-05-07 12:35:48.136 2013-05-07 13:45:10.366
CCAASTRA.L      2013-05-08 02:23:23.505 2013-05-08 04:18:05.096
```

My student can login and logout many time in one day and can logout in another day after his login

what must I do ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.studentname,
CASE
    WHEN a.eventtype = 1
    THEN a.eventdatetime
    END AS login,
CASE
    WHEN a.eventtype = 7
    THEN a.eventdatetime
   END AS logout

FROM student b INNER JOIN logstudent a ON b.studentid = a.studentid
WHERE b.active AND (a.eventtype = 1 OR a.eventtype = 7)
```

Comment: IF I try adding group by the output is false